# Is it possible to dispatch custom event types in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

Is it possible to dispatch custom ORM events to be picked up by event listeners in addition to the ones that come [prepackaged](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/events.html)?

For instance, even though the documentation [seems to be missing](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.MapperEvents.dispatch), it looks like I could dispatch an event by using `session.dispatch.before_update(mapper, session, self)` (or something similar, like I said, the documentation seems to be missing for this).

I wonder if it's also possible to dispatch custom events like, say `session.dispatch.my_custom_hook(mapper, session, self)`

Comment: Short answer no. Long answer maybe, if you are willing to go through the dance to create your own [mapper event class](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/events.py#L743) and then set up your own [mapper event dispatcher](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/events.py#L1536-L1547), and then [enable that for the mapper](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/main/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py#L854-L858). This is guesswork with only the internal documentation as the event definitions appears to be fully an internal API.

Comment: For dispatcher of ordinary events, yes, doing something like `session.dispatch.before_update(...)` can be done, but not recommended as there are already well-defined places where that's called.  Custom events are generally only available if the event system is defined to accept that via a public API, which `sqlalchemy` has not made it so.